# java.net.URLEncoder/Decoder alternatives

Tags: java

I found  [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Secure_Coding_Guideline#Banned_APIs)  that java.net.URLEncoder/Decoder shouldn't be used and instead of that, Encoder.encodeForURL()/decodeForURL() should be used. But I'm unable to find proper usage examples on the internet.
I'm curious about the reason what is the problem with URLEncoder or decoder. Kindly also tell how to use these functions.

I know that URLEncoder/decoder functions which take single arguments are deprecated because they don't take the character encoding format. But what is the problem with, say, something like this?

```
String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URL, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I think there is no problem t use it. This Method is not deprecated.

Comment: You read it in an arbitrary page of Internet junk whose link to their suggested replacement doesn't work. Why are you taking any notice at all?

Comment: Actually the client is testing our application through checkmarx and we have got a list of security issues. In the information-type issues, we have got this under "use of obsolete functions". I had no option but to search for its alternative. The page clearly looks outdated.

Comment: The answer is that it isn't obsolete, and the proof is in the Javadoc. If the client wants you to adhere to these recommendations, was it specified in the contract? and if so, why didn't you observe them during development? And, given that this page names a replacement, why aren't you using it? The page is from 2008 and provides an unexplained recommendation to reference that cannot be followed. It is useless.